# Spring form select modifing list items

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, jstl

The following jstl code is showing strange behaviour:

```
${property.bedrooms[0]}

<sf:select path="bedrooms[0]" multiple="multiple" items="${property.bedrooms[0].beds}" />

${property.bedrooms[0]}
```

The output is:

```
Bedroom{id=4, beds=[KING, QUEEN], enSuite=false} 

+-------------+
| KING        |
+-------------+

Bedroom{id=4, beds=[KING], enSuite=false}
```

Bedroom.toString() contains:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "Bedroom{" + "id=" + id + ", beds=" + beds + ", enSuite=" + enSuite + '}';
}
```

property.bedrooms[0].beds is a List<Enum>, and it seems that accessing it in the  items attribute is cutting out all but the first element!! Any idea what could be causing this?

Cheers!
NFV

Comment: Why is the second rendering of the bedroom instance different?

Comment: Thats what i cannot understand, it's beds list should not be modified by sf:select but it seems that it is?

Comment: What does the toString method on the bedroom class look like?  Does it call remove?

Comment: No, just standard - ive added it above

Comment: see my answer. It may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<sf:form modelAttribute="property">
    <sf:select path="bedrooms[0].beds" multiple="true">
        <sf:options />
    </sf:select>
</sf:form>
```

According to the spring-form(3.0.x) tld documentation and the source code java doc:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.options

If the bound value on the select is an enum spring will automatically use the list of all enum values for that class.

The itemLabel and itemValue properties of the options tag may be used to display a more user friendly label.

```
<sf:options itemLabel="friendlyName" />
```

Comment: Works perfectly, and makes sense now I think about it, Thanks!